# How to calculate ELF format .data section size manually

Tags: c, gcc, elf

I'd like to calculate the size of `.data` section in my program (compiled with gcc with no optimization) WITHOUT using `readelf` or any other tool, just by looking at the program. Is this possible? Here is the program:

ex1.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define FORMAT_STRING   "%s%" PRId64
#define MESSAGE         "The Oddonaci Number is: "

int64_t FastOddonacci(int32_t n);
int64_t LinearOddonacciHelper(int32_t n, int64_t current, int64_t first, int64_t second, int64_t third);
```

ex1.c

```
#include "ex1.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int32_t n = 40;
int32_t a = 3;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf(FORMAT_STRING, MESSAGE, FastOddonacci(n * a));
    return 0;
}

int64_t FastOddonacci(int32_t n) {
    if (n >= 1 && n <= 3) {
        return 1;
    }
    return LinearOddonacciHelper(n, 3, 1, 1, 1);
}

int64_t LinearOddonacciHelper(int32_t n, int64_t current, int64_t first, int64_t second, int64_t third) {
    if (n == current) {
        return third;
    }
    current += 1;
    return LinearOddonacciHelper(n, current, second, third, first+second+third);
}
```

From my understanding, `.data` section contains all initialized variables so here we should have two: `n` and `a`. The two in `#define` should go to `.rodata` instead. So we have 8 bytes in total.

However, `readelf` told me that the size is 0x18 = 24 bytes, why?

A second test: I changed both `n` and `a` to `int64_t` (and changed the signature of those functions) and `readelf` shew 32 bytes, which does make sense as the difference is exactly 8 bytes. Where is the missing 16 bytes? It doesn't look like alignment though.

Comment: The linker will add startup files which might have other global objects. For example the standard streams like `stdout` etc.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude, so it is rather difficult to calculate I guess, unless one is writing a compiler/linker and has to do the calculation.